# .is there any way to replace function bcpowmod

Tags: php, function, built-in

i want to use this function bcpowmod

```
$ri = bcpowmod($ciaa,(($p+1)/4), $p);
```

$ciaa = 70327810;
$p = 8009;

it show
"bc math warning: non-zero scale in exponent
1"
so how to fix it and get real result? Thank for helping me

Comment: Please add the `bcpowmod ` function code. Unless its not possible to check for problem.

Answer (score 0):

The exponent should be a non-negative, integral string (i.e. the scale has to be zero). In short, in your equation

`(($p+1)/4) is not integer`.

You can use

```
$ri = bcpowmod($ciaa,floor((($p+1)/4)), $p);
```

or

```
$ri = bcpowmod($ciaa,ceil((($p+1)/4)), $p);
```

Comment: When im input P : 523, Q : 647
Output :
C = 72205 -> RI = 40 -> SI = 397 -> XI = 72214 -> YI = 17219 -> M1 = 00010001101000010110 -> M2 = 01000000111110110111 -> M3 = 0100001101000011 -> M4 = 01001110011010001010 -> Square = m3 -> MI = 01000011 -> Huruf = C

Comment: When im input P : 8009, Q : 9413 Output : C = 70327810 -> RI = 1 -> SI = 9412 -> XI = 19437844 -> YI = 75388716 -> M1 = 00010010100100010100 -> M2 = 00110101111000011001 -> M3 = 01000111011100101100 -> M4 = 00000001000100000001 -> Square = -> MI = -> Huruf =

Comment: so the code wont work for that 4digit input
i think the problem on bcpowmod, but after i add floor , it solved the non-zero scale problem but the program not work
SC : https://ghostbin.co/paste/6hjvv , can you please take a look? Thanks

Comment: See the thing is floor and ceil rounds of your result to the nearest integer. It was just an example to demonstrate you the idea. In your code, you need to ensure that the exponent is an integer. For that you have to manage your own code.